# Why does the output differ between Genymotion and AVD when using the same Appium driver?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, appium, genymotion, saucelabs

I have a project set up to test an android apk file with Cucumber and Appium.

The project uses a standard support/env.rb that draws from an appium.txt file to do test setup. This is based off the appium sample code on the [appium github page](https://github.com/appium/sample-code/blob/master/sample-code/examples/ruby/cucumber_android/features/support/env.rb)

When I run the `arc` command it dumps me into a debug session. From there I run `page` which dumps the source from the driver. In the gem, in [appium_lib/android/helper.rb](https://github.com/appium/ruby_lib/blob/ea11190b9ab36e34226d988f85fe612af6f769de/lib/appium_lib/android/helper.rb) it calls @driver.page_source

So the driver is the same, and it's calling the same method on the driver, but the outputs are different

#### On Genymotion the output looks like:

```
android.widget.Button (0)
  text: Agree
  strings.xml: login_agree

android.widget.Button (1)
  text: Disagree [Quit]
  strings.xml: login_disagree
```

#### On AVD the output looks like:

```
android.widget.Button (0)
  text: Agree
  id: com.xxxxx.xxxxx:id/agree_btn
  strings.xml: login_agree

android.widget.Button (1)
  text: Disagree [Quit]
  id: com.xxxxx.xxxx:id/disagree_btn
  strings.xml: login_disagree
```

So `button("Agree").click` and `id("agree_btn").click` will work on AVD but not Genymotion.

Something like `button(1).click` will work on both.

Anyone know why this is/how to fix it so the Genymotion output is more verbose?

### Update:

Switching to a Genymotion device that uses API 19 seemed to fix the issue. The previous device was set to API 17. Still not sure why this would make a difference here.

When I used an avd device with API 17 the output was:

```
android.widget.Button (0)
  text: Agree
  strings.xml: login_agree

android.widget.Button (1)
  text: Disagree [Quit]
  strings.xml: login_disagree
```

The issue does not appear to be Genymotion specific.

Comment: What the output is looking like on an API 17 AVD? I want to know if we have something to fix on Genymotion or if the problem was due to the Android version you used.

Comment: update the answer to clear up the issue which appears to be an api issue. Thanks for the steerage.